# Async-await in multiple Winforms projects

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

We're trying to get status updates in the UI while the threads are running in the background. The following code is supposed to allow it but in practice we get the updates only once all threads are done and not while they are running. We also don't see significant performance improvement compared to running the task in serial so we might be doing something wrong here

The solution includes two projects with winForm with the first calling the second. WinClient namespace is used for the Winform client. It calls Services.modMain:

```
namespace WinClient
{
    static class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            //call another winform project and wait for it to complete
            Services.modMain.loadObjects().Wait();
            //run local form
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Service.modMain is where the application is continuously getting data and updating it in memory. When it does, it writes status messages to a splash form which remains open all the time. Once Service.modMain finishes the initial data load, Form1 (empty form in this exampl) should open while splashForm remains open as well

```
namespace Services
{
    public static class modMain
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {

        }

        public static async Task loadObjects()
        {
            frmSplash.DefInstance.LoadMe();

            Progress<PrintToSplashMessage> messageToWindow = new Progress<PrintToSplashMessage>();
            messageToWindow.ProgressChanged += reportProgress;

            frmSplash.DefInstance.print_to_window("Starting Services", Color.Black, true);

            Task<bool> load1Task = load1(messageToWindow);
            Task<bool> load2Task = load2(messageToWindow);
            await Task.WhenAll(load1Task, load2Task);

        }

        private static async Task<bool> load2(IProgress<PrintToSplashMessage> progress)
        {
            return await Task<bool>.Run(() =>
            {
                PrintToSplashMessage theMessage = new PrintToSplashMessage("Load2, please wait...", Color.Black, true, false);
                progress.Report(theMessage);
                for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100); // CPU-bound work
                }
                return true;
            });
        }

        private static async Task<bool> load1(IProgress<PrintToSplashMessage> progress)
        {
            return await Task<bool>.Run(() =>
            {
                PrintToSplashMessage theMessage = new PrintToSplashMessage("Load1, please wait...", Color.Black, true, false);
                progress.Report(theMessage);
                for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100); // CPU-bound work
                }
                return true;
            });
        }

        private static void reportProgress(object sender, PrintToSplashMessage e)
        {
            frmSplash.DefInstance.PrintToSplashWindow(e);
        }
    }
}
```

PrintToSplashWindow is just a utility class to store progress data:

```
namespace Services
{
    public class PrintToSplashMessage
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public Color MessageColor { get; set; }
        public bool OnNewLine { get; set; }
        public bool PrintToLog { get; set; }

        public PrintToSplashMessage(String theMessage, Color theMessageColor, bool isOnNewLine, bool needPrintToLog)
        {
            Message = theMessage;
            MessageColor = theMessageColor;
            OnNewLine = isOnNewLine;
            PrintToLog = needPrintToLog;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here's frmSplash:

```
namespace Services
{
    public partial class frmSplash : Form
    {

        public frmSplash() :base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public void PrintToSplashWindow(PrintToSplashMessage theMessage)
        {
            print_to_window(theMessage.Message, theMessage.MessageColor, theMessage.OnNewLine);
        }

        public void print_to_window(string strShortMsg, Color lngColor, bool blnOnNewLine)
        {
            string strNewLine = String.Empty;
            if (blnOnNewLine)
            {
                if ( rtbErrorDisplay.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    strNewLine = Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else
                {
                    strNewLine = "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strNewLine = "";
            }
            rtbErrorDisplay.SelectionStart = rtbErrorDisplay.Text.Length;
            rtbErrorDisplay.SelectionColor = lngColor;
            rtbErrorDisplay.SelectedText = strNewLine + strShortMsg;
            rtbErrorDisplay.SelectionStart = rtbErrorDisplay.Text.Length;
            rtbErrorDisplay.ScrollToCaret();

            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

What we expect is that frmSplash would show the progress messages as the tasks are runing in the background. In practice, it only show all at bulk when everything is done.

Comment: There is too much code in this question. I am sure you could reduce the code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem. Less code = more chances to get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Short version: the only thing that ever processes window messages in the code you posted is a call to `Application.DoEvents()`. But the code likely never gets that far, or if it does, the call happens on the wrong thread.

Longer version:

You didn't include an actual [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I didn't bother to test, but the `Progress` class relies on a synchronization context to work. Since you haven't called `Application.Run()`, there's may be no sync context at all. In which case `Progress` is just going to use the thread pool to invoke whatever handlers subscribed to it.

That would mean that when you call `Application.DoEvents()`, you're in a thread pool thread, not the thread that owns your splash window.

Windows are owned by threads, and their messages go to that thread's message queue. The `Application.DoEvents()` method will retrieve messages for the *current* thread's message queue, but does nothing to process messages for other threads' queues.

In the worst case, there *is* a sync context for that thread (I can't recall…it's possible that since the thread is STA, the framework has created one for you), but since you have no message loop, nothing queued to it ever gets dispatched. The progress reports just keep piling up and never processed.

You should abandon `Application.DoEvents()` altogether. Calling `DoEvents()` is *always* a kludge, and there's *always* a better option.

In this case, use `Application.Run()` for the first form as well (the splash screen). Create that form and subscribe to its `FormShown` event so that you know when to call `loadObjects()`. At the end of that method, close the form, so `Application.Run()` will return and go on to the next `Application.Run()` call.

Here is a sample based on the code you did post, with me filling in the details (for both forms, just use the Designer to create a default `Form` object…the rest of the initialization is in the user code below).

For the splash screen class, I inferred most of it, and took the rest straight from your code. The only change I made to your code was to remove the call to `Application.DoEvents()`:

```cs
partial class SplashScreen : Form
{
    public static SplashScreen Instance { get; } = new SplashScreen();

    private readonly RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();

    public SplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // 
        // richTextBox1
        // 
        richTextBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
        richTextBox1.Location = new Point(13, 13);
        richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
        richTextBox1.Size = new Size(775, 425);
        richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        Controls.Add(richTextBox1);
    }

    public void PrintToSplashWindow(PrintToSplashMessage theMessage)
    {
        print_to_window(theMessage.Message, theMessage.MessageColor, theMessage.OnNewLine);
    }

    public void print_to_window(string strShortMsg, Color lngColor, bool blnOnNewLine)
    {
        string strNewLine = String.Empty;
        if (blnOnNewLine)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                strNewLine = Environment.NewLine;
            }
            else
            {
                strNewLine = "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            strNewLine = "";
        }
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = lngColor;
        richTextBox1.SelectedText = strNewLine + strShortMsg;
        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }
}
```

It's not clear to me why you have two different classes, both of which seem to be set up as the entry point for the program. I consolidated those into a single class:

```cs
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        loadObjects();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public static void loadObjects()
    {
        SplashScreen.Instance.Shown += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            Progress<PrintToSplashMessage> messageToWindow = new Progress<PrintToSplashMessage>();
            messageToWindow.ProgressChanged += reportProgress;

            SplashScreen.Instance.print_to_window("Starting Services", Color.Black, true);

            Task<bool> load1Task = load1(messageToWindow);
            Task<bool> load2Task = load2(messageToWindow);
            await Task.WhenAll(load1Task, load2Task);
            SplashScreen.Instance.Close();
        };

        SplashScreen.Instance.ShowDialog();
    }

    private static async Task<bool> load2(IProgress<PrintToSplashMessage> progress)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            PrintToSplashMessage theMessage = new PrintToSplashMessage("Load2, please wait...", Color.Black, true, false);
            progress.Report(theMessage);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // CPU-bound work
                theMessage.Message = $"Load2, i = {i}";
                progress.Report(theMessage);
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    private static async Task<bool> load1(IProgress<PrintToSplashMessage> progress)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            PrintToSplashMessage theMessage = new PrintToSplashMessage("Load1, please wait...", Color.Black, true, false);
            progress.Report(theMessage);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // CPU-bound work
                theMessage.Message = $"Load1, i = {i}";
                progress.Report(theMessage);
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    private static void reportProgress(object sender, PrintToSplashMessage e)
    {
        SplashScreen.Instance.PrintToSplashWindow(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter,Thank you for your response. We are are trying to implement your suggestion. Meanwhile, can you please let me know what's missing in order to make my code snippets above MCVE? There are no others classes/forms in the solution (other than Form1 which is an empty form for the purpose of the example.

Comment: Your code example is missing most of the `frmSplash` code. I can infer the `RichTextBox`, but you don't know initialization nor the declaration of the `Instance` property. I could infer those too, but the more inferences I have to make, the greater the chance there's something weird in your code that I wind up not taking into account. It's better if you just put _all_ of the code in your post, and make sure it's _minimal_. It's even best if you can leave out the Designer-generated code and just instantiate any controls directly in the constructor (like the `RichTextBox`).

Comment: I had a few spare moments, so I went ahead and made the assumptions I needed to make to put together a complete sample. Please see edit above. Hopefully, my assumptions don't differ from your actual implementation too much. For what it's worth, if they do, I'll encourage you to change your code to be modeled after mine. :)

Comment: Hi Peter and thank you so much for the code sample. We did try switching over to application.Run - as you suggested - but the problem is that Form1 won't start until the SplashScreen is closed. In our scenario we must keep both open. Also, we use two different entry point for historical reasons (the application was migrated from VB6...) and trying to merge the two in the real code might be too much work. So if we can make the threading work properly in the current structure, it would be best :). Thank you, Ken

Comment: _"the problem is that Form1 won't start until the SplashScreen is closed"_ -- that is a simple thing to address, but it is (frankly) exactly the kind of missing detail in your question's code that makes it impossible to provide a code example that _exactly_ meets your needs. Indeed, the code example you posted would not show the `Form1` until the splash screen is over either. So your statement that you want both forms open at once is a _new requirement_.

Comment: Sorry about it. I added explanation of how the two projects/forms interacts

Comment: @KenSaraf: I'm sure you mean well, but the shifting requirements make your line of question into what I view as a [Chameleon Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). I have answered the basic question you originally posed. ...

Comment: ... My answer provides sufficient detail for you to see how to apply the same approach in a different scenario, such as where you want multiple forms active at once (you can still use the `Shown` event to trigger initialization). If after making some effort to apply that information you still need help, posting a new question would be in order. Be sure that question includes a good [mcve].